# Redux - how to pass a generated prop to a sibling selector function?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have this component:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    id: getId(state),
    item: getItem(state, ownProps.id),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Foo);
```

My `getItem` selector requires the `id` that is generated by a sibling selector, `getId`. I gather that `ownProps` will only contain the props passed to `<Foo />` (there are none in my case, so `ownProps` is empty). So, is there a way to do this internally within the `Foo` component, or do I have to use the `getId` selector in the parent component of `Foo` and explicitly pass `id` as a prop to `Foo` like this `<Foo id={id} />`?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, code shows `ownProps.id` but in your question you say ownProps is empty so that code doesn't make sense. Maybe `item: getItem(state, getId(state))` will work but your question don't make a lot of sense maybe it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `getId` selector directly in the `getItem` selector:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    ...
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    id: getId(state),
    item: getItem(state, getId(state)),
});
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Foo);